# Scan ceph storage with local anti-virus

Tags: php, amazon-s3, antivirus, ceph

I'm accessing a ceph storage in php as discribed in here ([Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html)), is it possible to scan objects in that storage (without downloading them) using a command line anti-virus scanner which is running through php using `shell_exec()`?
or do I have to download objects them scan them locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to download them. Even if you were local to the storage, there's no guarantees of a 1:1 mapping between the file as exposed to S3 vs the file(s) on disk.

You could have something that implicitly downloaded them, or explicitly download them first. Doing it yourself might be better if you have some very large objects, so you can consider skipping them, or handling them in a special way.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I did. I download the object, scan it, then delete it and send results. Thanks for your response.